# Maps on mobile too detailed to read. Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, blackberry-10

I'm working on a mobile website with map support.

The roads and font on mobile maps are too small to read. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA30t.jpg)

I would like it to show less detail at this zoom level.

Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks,

Casey Forsyth

PS: I have tested this on a HTC Ace and a BB Z10
The Z10 is more readable but would be very hard to read without perfect eye sight.

Comment: How did you implement it? Maybe it thinks it's a computer, and that's why a small font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by shrinking the size of everything else around the map and since the page is scaled to fit the view port it scaled nicely.